# Rosjava and Arduino

Tags: arduino, rosjava, ros-electric

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

Is it possible to use Rosjava with Arduino?
Are there any tutoials or packges yet developed about that?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/42453/rosjava-and-arduino/) by [camilla](https://answers.ros.org/users/2828/camilla/) on ROS Answers with karma: 255 on 2012-08-27

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [damonkohler](https://answers.ros.org/users/653/damonkohler/) on 2012-09-12**:
In what capacity do you want to do this? Obviously, the JVM cannot run on an Arduino. Do you want to communicate with an Arduino? I suggest looking into rosserial.

**Comment by [camilla](https://answers.ros.org/users/2828/camilla/) on 2012-09-19**:
Thank you rosserial is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Try using rosserial: http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosserial

---

Originally posted by [damonkohler](https://answers.ros.org/users/653/damonkohler/) with karma: 3838 on 2012-10-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1